# Programmatically communicate with multiple unfocused VMWare instances with C#

Tags: c#, vmware, communication, keystroke

Even though my long title spoils quite a lot of my question, I'll try to be more specific here.

I have 5 VMWare instances that all have their own tasks to do. They are hosted on one same computer. But I need one program (that I'm actually writing, duh) to get informations and to send informations such as keystrokes and mouse clicks. But from what I've red so far, communication between programs is quite hard to achieve and I haven't found any way to send keystrokes to an unfocused or reduced VMWare windows. Plus I would need to send different and specific keystrokes to each of my 5 VMWare instances.

My program will starts itself each 5 tasks in each 5 windows. The order doesn't matter as long as each instances have its own tasklist. I would need a way to keep track on each window's identity so I don't send let's say window 4's keystrokes to window 5. I would also need to be able to check periodically if each VMWare's instances is doing its job. Additionnaly my VMWare's instances are all running in a win7 environnement.

Now that the whole situation is explained, I'll sum up the question I'm currently submitting. Is there any way for my C# program to keep track of 5 VMWare's instances' identities and both send keystrokes (+ mouseclicks) and get at least screenshots of what's displayed on each of them even though they are reduced or unfocused ?

Thanks a lot.

Is there a way to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect understanding of how VMWare works. VMWare isn't "running in a window". VMWare is running in a virtual machine at a very low level in your computer. What you see as a "window" is merely a "viewer" that allows you to connect to the remote machine (even though it's running on the local computer). This "viewer" is an application similar to the remote desktop client, or a VNC client. As such, there is very limited interaction between the OS and the host OS and the applications running in the guests.

This means that your host OS doesn't know anything about the individual applications running inside the guest OS, and you can't see it's window handles, or control mouse or keyboard events.  In fact, the VMWare drivers "capture" the hardware and steal these events directly from the hardware, so there is no real way for your application to simulate a human interacting with the Virtual machine window.

What you COULD do, and this would be a lot of work, is create "agents" on each of the virtual machines that would have access to the applications running on them.  These agents could listen for events on the network, and you could send events to them to do what you want.  However, as I said.. this is likely a lot of work.

This whole thing sounds kind of cheesy to begin with, like you're trying to do something the hard way, but since you haven't told us what you're ACTUALLY trying to do.. we can't suggest any better alternatives.

Comment: "In fact, the VMWare drivers "capture" the hardware and steal these events directly from the hardware, so there is no real way for your application to simulate a human interacting with the Virtual machine window."

I understand. Your message was really instructive. So each VMWare's instances (which I shouldn't call "instances" I guess) should at least share the same network and be able to communicate with each others through this network, wouldn't they ? So one way to achieve my goal would be to have my main application to send the informations through the network. Or am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: (sorry for the double post)

I understand how frustrating it can be to answer someone that isn't giving informations that are enough specific. Besides my difficulties to express myself and explain the situation (which is the main reason behind my unspecificness) I wanted a quite generic answer because I know I might have to handle the same problem again in another situation.

Thanks a lot, really, for your answer. And the one below yours too, which is something I'll look into too. At least for learning purpose !

Comment: @RobertArctor - No, it's fine to call them instances, but they're instances of virtual machines running at a low level of the hardware.  Yes, depending on how you've configured the virtual network switches, they can all share a common network (including sharing it with the host, or even the internet).  Yes, you send and receive information through the network to individual "agents" you run in each VM instance, those "agents" then have full access to the guest OS and applications (depending on the permissions you run them as) to do what you need.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. And that seems pretty simple to do too! One last thing, if you don't mind, would they be able to communicate with each others through localhost or is localhost specific to each machines? If so, should I make them communicate through my router? I guess I'll get to know that by testing myself as well.

Thanks a lot for your insight !

Comment: @RobertArctor - yes, localhost is specific to each virtual machine with each machine having its own network stack and IP address.  You have to think of each VM as if it were its own physical computer.  VMWare defines a "virtual switch" which you define how your networking works, and you can do it however you want.

Comment: That's even better than I initially thought ! And it'll prove even more useful, really ! Thanks a lot again (: ! 

So yeah. Each instances is to be seen as a "physical" computer even though it is virtual. I think I got myself fooled by the term "emulate" that I often saw people use along with VMWare. 

My problem is fully solved (:

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty approach is to look into Visual Studio Test Controller and Agents. The idea is to install the agent on each one of the machines. You can then leverage the MSTest framework (wrongly called unit tests) to execute you c# code one each agent.